# Master bone not moving rig properly

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints

[image: bad bone]I have parented all controller bones and IK bones in my IK rig to a master bone. When I select all controller and IK bones I can move the rig fine. However, when I try to move the rig with the master bone the rig acts like it's being dragged around and ends up leaning in all sorts of strange directions. I'm not sure how to describe it. The image here shows kinda what's going on. The instant I parented everything to the master bone, stuff went wrong.[image: edit mode]

[image: without bone]

Here you can see how I can move it just fine without master bone. Does anyone have any ideas why this may be happening? I've been searching everywhere but every question I find talks about bones not moving the mesh properly.

Answer (score -1):

So I found out that I had to set the constraints on one of my bones to a number greater than 0.